# VB.NET get specific cell value from excel

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am trying to evaluate if specific cell value in an excel table is "" to use in an if statement in my VB.NET application. I modified the code that I use for writing to excel, but it doesn't work to get the cell value. The code I have:

```
   Sub Excel_LoadProjectsSchedule()

        xlApp = New Excel.Application
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("G:\100 Databases\Projects Schedule.xlsx")
        xlApp.Visible = False
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("sheet1")
        Dim ProjectFinished  as boolean

        'Set variables
        Result = xlWorkSheet.Cells.Find(ProjectNumber, LookAt:=Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole)

        If xlWorkSheet.Cells(Result.Row, 3).value = "" Then
            ProjectFinished = False
        Else
            ProjectFinished = True
        End If

        'Save and close
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
        xlWorkBook.Close(SaveChanges:=True)
        xlApp.Quit()

    End Sub
```

Error is on

```
If xlWorkSheet.Cells(Result.Row, 3).value = "" Then
```

And it says "System.MissingMemberException: 'Public member 'value' on type 'Range' not found.'
"

I do have

```
Public xlApp As Excel.Application = Nothing
Public xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
Public xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing
```

Outside the sub in this module.

What am I doing wrong, could someone, please, help me solve this one?

Comment: I don't know VB.Net but my first guess would be that the item is not found. Have you checked that?

Comment: That's what the error says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some casting so the compiler can recognize the types.

```
Sub Excel_LoadProjectsSchedule(ProjectNumber As Integer)

    Dim xlApp = New Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("G:\100 Databases\Projects Schedule.xlsx")
    xlApp.Visible = False
    Dim xlWorkSheet = DirectCast(xlWorkBook.Worksheets("sheet1"), Excel.Worksheet)
    Dim ProjectFinished As Boolean

    'Set variables
    Dim Result = xlWorkSheet.Cells.Find(ProjectNumber, LookAt:=Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole)
    Dim row = Result.Row
    Dim cell = DirectCast(xlWorkSheet.Cells(row, 3), Excel.Range)
    If cell.Value Is Nothing Then
        'What do you want to do?
    Else
        If cell.Value.ToString = "" Then
            ProjectFinished = False
        Else
            ProjectFinished = True
        End If
    End If

    'Save and close
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    xlWorkBook.Close(SaveChanges:=True)
    xlApp.Quit()

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey thanks this works, not sure how it works though, but still!

Comment: @Eduards It is simply that the compiler was treating `xlWorkSheet` and `cell` as Objects. Object doesn't have a Cells property or a Value property. We can use `DirectCast` which skips some checking (is a bit faster) since we are sure what the object really is. With Option Strict On this type of problem will show up.

Comment: It does not work on the firt IF statement line if the cell value is in fact ""

Comment: Why could that be?

Comment: `Cells(row, 3)` is referring to column C. Is that the column you wish to target?

Comment: I added a check for null for the value of the cell. Not sure what you want to do if it is null.

Comment: If cell value is "" then ProjectFinished = False and if it's not "" then ProjectFinished = True. It literally says it in the code
````
        If cell.Value.ToString = "" Then
            ProjectFinished = False
        Else
            ProjectFinished = True
        End If
````

Comment: I get that it doesn't actually want to take action if value is "", just spits out an error and that's it. I tried all teh combinations I can think of with = nullable, is nothing, = nothing and so on

Comment: If the cell is empty, the `Value` is `Nothing`, not `""`. You cannot call `ToString` on `Nothing`. What is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: Ah alright I got it, so the code that actually does the thing is as follows:
````
        If DirectCast(xlWorkSheet.Cells(Result.Row, 3), Excel.Range).Value Is Nothing Then
            ProjectFinished = False
        Else
            ProjectFinished = True
        End If
````

Answer (score 1):

I think if you specifically want to check contents in the 3rd Column of the Row with that Projectnumber you're not far away from the Solution.
I only tested it inside of VBA but something along the Lines of:

```
Sub Excel_LoadProjectsSchedule()
    Dim xlWorksheet As Worksheet, Result As Range, ProjectFinished  As Boolean
    xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("G:\100 Databases\Projects Schedule.xlsx")
    xlApp.Visible = False
    Set xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("sheet1")
    
    'Set variables
     Set Result = xlWorksheet.Cells.Find(Projectnumber, LookIn:=Excel.XlLookin.xlValues, LookAt:=Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole)
     if not Result is nothing then
     If Cells(Result.Row, 3).Value = "" Then
         ProjectFinished = False
     Else
         ProjectFinished = True
     End If
 End Sub
```

The Problem being, that "Result" hasn't been asigned to a Range, so your code coudn't access the Row Property.

Comment: Same result. First of all "XlLookin" does not exist so I used "XlFindLookIn" and result is still the same - same error

Comment: The error happened on 
`If Cells(Result.Row, 3).Value` , right?
What does Result return after the `.Find` line?

Comment: Yes, it returns nothing which is the same as in the code I use to write to that same specific cell. This code is just the reverse of that. Result is a line of code shortened to one word as you can see in the code

Comment: Yeah i know that Result is just the Variable... but what is the Value of that Variable after you asigned it? If it is Nothing after the asignment then it's no wonder you're getting the error

Comment: at the momet of error "Result" is nothing same as it is nothing while running my code thatfinds the "ProjectNumber" and writes the value to the excel as opposed to here where it is supposed to get the value. I am pretty sure it has nothing to do with the result , but with "value" or "text" etc because all of them returns the same error. In my writing code the neither one is used (".Value", ".Text") and it works there, however here it doesn't... gives all kinds of errors

Comment: huh, well, then I'm deeply sorry. My understanding of VB.NET isn't nearly good enough to be of help to you.

Answer (score 0):

If looking for a certain cell in certain row .

```
 Dim AppExcel As Object
    Dim workBook As Object
    AppExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    workBook = AppExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\SO\SO.xlsx")
    AppExcel.Visible = False

    Worksheets = workBook.worksheets
    If Worksheets("Blad1").Cells(2, 3).text = "" Then

        MessageBox.Show("Empty")

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Text")
    End If
```

Then the close part